# Refresh a certain sheet associated with multiple connections

Tags: excel, vba, database, connection, refresh

I've been struggling this question for a long time and wonder if anyone can help. There is a workbook with five sheets, and the data on these sheets are created through using my company's connections which really contain massive data. I'm not sure if I can call the connections as database. And each time I click RefreshAll on any sheet, it will refresh all the data and takes 10min around.

The question is I want to use a VBA code to refresh sheet 1 only because the data on sheet2-4 are not used often and the running time can be saved. If I do it without VBA, I simply right click the data table then click refresh instead refresh all. Thank you

```
Sub Cube_Refresh()
                
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll 'this code will refresh all sheets and I tried worksheet1.refresh but this method doesn't exist
   
End Sub
```